# Changing positions of sprites and buttons made in SpriteBuilder

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I've made 3 buttons in SpriteBuilder, named them _bt1, _bt2 and _bt3 and made a selector for each.
Selectors work fine but when I try to change their positions in codes they just don't move.

```
[_bt1 setPosition:ccp(435, 287)];
bt1.position=ccp(435,287);
```

Both don't work at all.
Other sprites made in codes move alright.

Is there something I should do to make sprites and buttons in SpriteBuilder???

Thanks,

Comment: check whether these ivars are nil, set a breakpoint

Comment: I tried the same thing in the new project and worked fine.
Seems like they work fine in didLoadFromCCB method.
I was trying it in init.

thx for your advice!